# Swap values in second dictionary as keys in first dictionary - Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I have tow dictionaries

```
my_dict = {1 : 1.8 , 2 : 1.2 , 3 : 0.6}
mapping_dict = {1 : "Number_1_fruit" , 2 : "Number_2_fruit" , 3 : "Number_3_fruit"}
```

I want to first check if a key in my_dict exists in mapping_dict, and if it does; replace the key in my_dict with the value of mapping_dict.

The result I expect is

```
my_dict = {"Number_1_fruit" : 1.8 , ""Number_2_fruit" : 1.2 , "Number_3_fruit" : 0.6}
```

I have tris this code and everything else I came across on the net with no success.

```
my_dict = {1 : 1.8 , 2 : 1.2 , 3 : 0.6}
mapping_dict = {1 : "Number_1_fruit" , 2 : "Number_2_fruit" , 3 : "Number_3_fruit"}

for k,v in my_dict.items():
     if k in mapping_dict:
        value = mapping_dict[k]
        my_dict[value] = mapping_dict[v]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try dictionary-comprehension + [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```py
my_dict = {1 : 1.8 , 2 : 1.2 , 3 : 0.6}
mapping_dict = {1 : "Number_1_fruit" , 2 : "Number_2_fruit" , 3 : "Number_3_fruit"}


my_dict = {mapping_dict.get(k, k): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}
print(my_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{'Number_1_fruit': 1.8, 'Number_2_fruit': 1.2, 'Number_3_fruit': 0.6}
```